# Can Arjuna's statements in Bhagavad Gita be taken as pramAna i.e., are they on par with Krishna’s?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, arjuna

Such as

> 1.41 - When unrighteousness prevails, O Krishna the women of the clan become corrupt; when women become corrupt, there arises intermixture of castes.
>
> 1.43 - By the crimes of the clan-destroyers who bring about intermingling of castes, the ancient traditions of the clan and caste are destroyed.

Comment: Yes, I think all major commentators take Arjuna's words seriously.

Comment: Anything mentioned in Mahabharata is as authoritative as the scripture itself. It does not matter who is saying so .. It might be Yudhisthira, Bhisma or anybody else but at the end it's Mahabharata which is saying so.

Comment: Nope. Arjuna's words can't be taken on par with Krishna... But still Arjuna is perfectly conscientious here.

Comment: Suppose we take a statement of Yama found in the Vedas and a statement of Krishna found in a Purana.. which will have more weight between the two? obviously its the Vedic passage irrespective of who has made those statements .. so we have to judge the weight of scriptures according to the standard rule Vedas>Smritis>Puranas .. there is no way of discriminating passages found in the **same scripture** depending on which characters have made the statements. That's just absurd and subjective.

Comment: there is a famous story in Tamil - a poet accuses Siva of making a mistake in his poem.  Siva shows him the third eye and the poet says "even if you show your third eye, a mistake is a mistake".  @rickross you have opened a huge can of worms on scriptural authority - a human in the Veda versus a God in the Puranas  -it looks like you would take the human :-)

Comment: "there is no way of discriminating passages found in the same scripture" I dont think this is correct. If Duryodhana and Dharma Raja both say that they have always followed dharma, both statements are not on an equal footing. @rickross

Comment: @SK The traditional position is that vedas are eternal and it is not humans making these statements. These are all allegories. As an example, the story of Yama and Nachiketa and many other vedic stories are treated as allegories by Shankara himself.

Comment: There is no scriptural method of doing so to my knowledge.. the answers will vary depending on opinions and that's why it's subjective ..If someone asks which one has more weight? - a statement made by Vidura in MB or one made by Yudhisthira within the same scripture? .. that's just opinion based nothing else. @yAdRcchika

Comment: @rickross Everything is opinion anyway. Even the statement that there is no way of discriminating passages within the same scripture is also an opinion.

Comment: I think there is an authority rule Shrutis>Smritis>itihasas. Now if there are contradicting view points within same scripture then one needs to read the entire scripture. For instance Bhisma stated that sticking to vow was the highest Dharma. And if you stop there you will come out with wrong/incomplete information.

Comment: @Rickross I think for Vedic injunctions, since they are authorless, the vidhis are spoken by an authorless being, so they are accepted as true just because they are authorless vedic statements. But for authored works like smritis which are just recordings of historic events, the character of the person who makes the smriti statement matters when compared to a smriti statement made by another person.

Comment: I don't think they matter .. it's all subjective .. We say "Mahabharata says" (and the authority of that statement=authority of MB) ... X Purana says etc.. Also, who says does not matter, otherwise different portions of a Purana will have different authority, which is of course absurd.. also it is not that, a person who is evil or incapable, can't give advice that are worthy to be followed by others .. in Hinduism, even  what a Vyadha (butcher or hunter) says on Dharma, is of high merit (Vyadha Gita).. @Ikshvaku

Answer (score 2):

> Can Arjuna's statements in Bhagavad Gita be taken as pramAna i.e., are they on par with Krishna’s?

**Yes.** All ancient Vaidika commentators take that as a pramana and for good reasons that I will explain.

Arjuna was worthy enough to receive the teachings of the Gita personally. To not believe him is equivalent to rejecting the Gita itself.

He is also re-iterating to Krishna the beliefs that were common during his time and even before: that the caste system is birth-based. Arjuna's claim is made by other reputable people in the Mahabharata like Yudhishthira, Bhishma, etc.

Bhishma, the speaker of the auspicious Vishnu Sahasranama, [says the same thing](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b013.htm):

> ...by uniting themselves with women of other castes, led not by considerations of righteousness but by uncontrolled lust, cause numerous mixed castes to come into existence whose occupations and abodes depend on the circumstances connected with the irregular unions to which they owe their origin.

Moreover, this claim is made by the Vedas themselves, and Jaimini has even written a sutra for it in the Purva Mimamsa Sutras, which are also commented upon by Shabara:

The Vedic verse is:

> "We do not know if we are Brahmanas or non-Brahmanas ... Therefore, When the pravaras [ancestral lineages] are being recounted, one should say the deities are our ancestors- (Maitrayaniya Samhita 1.4.11 of the Krishna Yajur Veda).

The Vedic verse shows that the castes are based on ancestry (gotra), and hence, birth-based. If caste wasn't based on ancestry, then it would be useless to mention pravaras in that verse in relation to caste.

The Mimamsa Sutra for that verse is:

> On account of the failings of women, (there can be no certainty regarding one's caste); specially as the son belongs to the progenitor. - Adhyaya 1, Pada 2, Sutra 13

And Shabara's commentary:

> It is difficult to know if one is really a Brahmana; - and this is what is figuratively spoken of as "we do not know", and the difficulty in knowing it for certain is due to "the failings of women", and also to the fact that "the son belongs to the progenitor"; this is also indicated by the advice "May you guard this dynastic line with great care." - Apastamba Dharma Sutra 2.6.13.6

Now to reject Arjuna's statements as apramana, is to reject authorities like Arjuna himself, the honorable recipient of the Gita, Shabara, Jaimini, the Pandavas, the Mahabharata, Bhishma, Vishnu Sahasranama, Krishna, and even the Vedas themselves.

This is to be expected from neo-Vedantins anyways, since they are after all, unorthodox.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what Arjuna himself thought of Krishna's teaching given in the Gita. Arjuna in fact asked Krishna to again lecture his Gita teachings after the end of the war. Krishna was annoyed with Arjuna and gave a summary of the Gita teachings which is known as Anu Gita.

> Having been thus addressed, the greatly energetic Krishna, supreme
>   among eloquent ones, embraced Phalguna and replied in these words, **"I
>   made you listen to something that is eternal and secret. O Partha!
>   That was about the nature of eternal dharma for all the worlds. I am
>   greatly displeased that you have ignorantly not grasped what I told
>   you. O Pandava! It is evident that you have not been faithful, or your
>   intelligence is not adequate. That dharma is sufficient to obtain the
>   state of the brahman. However, I am incapable of telling you
>   everything in detail again. I immersed myself in yoga and told you
>   about the supreme brahman.** But I will tell you about an ancient
>   history with the same purport. Using that, if you use your
>   intelligence, you will reach the ultimate destination, O best among
>   those who uphold dharma! ...

*Mahabharata, Ashvamedhika Parva, Chapter 1851 (16) translated by Bibek Debroy*

This episode suggests that Arjuna himself recognised the worth of Krishna's teachings in the Gita and made no claim that his stray comments are of any importance. Hence Arjuna's statements are not pramana.

Comment: "made no claim that his stray comments are of any importance. " - Would you believe him if he said his comments are of importance? And they are not "stray" by the way, many other reputable people like Yudhishthira state the same exact things in the Mahabharata.